# Python: Two Dictionaries in JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

After managing a JSON file inside Pandas, I find that inside a single cell, I'm having a JSON, where inside I have two or more dictionaries. As in this example, in the cell "Addresses", the JSON file can contain multiple addresses.

```
"addresses": [
    {
        "address": "SomeWay 88",
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    },
    {
        "address": "SomeWay 89",
        "city": "Boston",
        "country": "USA"
    }
]
```

In Pandas, if I create a function, I et only the First result, and I lose the second. How can I create a Loop that managed to deal with all the occurrences presente inside the cell?

Comment: Maybe you can handle the data cell as array.. it is possible? Can you insert lines of your code?

Comment: Can you share expected output?

Comment: Are you converting the JSON to a DataFrame? If so, can you post the full JSON?